# How to change supply line to my dishwasher with this valve type?

Tags: plumbing

The supply line from under my sink to my dishwasher is leaking and I wanted to replace it. However, the line connect to the water supply as shown below using this type of plastic valve (what is this valve called)?  As you can see, there is not way to unscrew the supply line - the hose is part of the valve.

How would you replace this hose?  Can I unscrew the entire valve from the water supply line and put a sharkbite or something on it?

If I had a plumber replace this, any idea what it should run?

PS if I have to cut this hose, would it be easily cut or would I need a special tool?  For example I have some strong loppers for cutting tree branches...

[image]

Comment: "Dishwasher Inlet Hose Valve"  It may have come with the machine so that would be the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a way to remove the valve from the red pipe.  I'd spend about a minute trying.   Maybe that plastic sleeve under your thumb is a remover widget.  Maybe not.   After a minute I'd just cut the red pipe and shove a Sharkbite appliance valve on it, and a new high quality appliance hose.  How to cut PEX is something you can look up and the Sharkbite valve comes with instructions.  I would attach the PEX to a wall with pipe clamps so it and the valve aren't flapping around in the cabinet.

Comment: Thanks this is what I ended up deciding to go with after lots of research.  Good call on the attaching to clamp

Answer (score 1):

I'd shut off the water somewhere further upstream, *drain the line*, then disconnect the valve from the red PEX and put a new valve & hose on there.

What it would cost is *entirely* dependent on where you live and is, therefore, off-topic according to SE rules. However, it's probably going to cost more today than it would have 2 years ago.